# sql server management studio syntax

Tags: sql-server, syntax, ssms

Can some one explain the significant of the brackets that MSManagement Studio always encapsulates columns in queries with. 
Ex..

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
  ,[app_fn]
  ,[app_mn]
  ,[app_ln]
  ,[app_suffix]
```

What are they there for, and how can I use this to my advantage?

Comment: Just to be clear: this is perfectly valid T-SQL syntax which will work everywhere - *not* just in SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They allow to use identifiers that

- have spaces
- are reserved keywords
- start with a number
- use punctuation
- [otherwise invalid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Try this without the [ and ]

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[CREATE TABLE] (
    [SELECT] int NOT NULL, 
    [int] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [NOT NULL] datetime NULL,
    [Mary's Lamb] datetime NULL,
    [666 The number of the "beast"!] datetime NULL
    )
```

In this case, SSMS just always uses them

Answer (score 7):

They are normally used if you are using a `keyword` as a column name. (Naughty)

Also, if you have a `space` in your column name (also naughty).

Comment: And to protect you if your column is a reserved word. Also naughty.

Comment: +1 ..Also they can be used to specify column names that are same as keywords in SQL..for example `SELECT 'SOMETHING' [SELECT]`

Comment: Carrying on a meme-theme within comments is *also naughty*

Comment: SSMS is just being cautious when it's generating scripts on your behalf. In practice, I would strangle anyone who used a reserved word for a table/function/procedure as no one wants to type `[]` in their queries.

Comment: @Yuck - Cats don't have thumbs and can't "strangle"

Comment: @Yuck - this is true, but having thumbs is more efficient!

Answer (score 4):

Heres an example

I have a table called groups, it has fields user, group

well, user and group are both reserved words, by automatically putting the square brackets around table, fields etc no problems will arise.

so

```
select group from groups group by user
```

would fail

```
select [group] from [groups] group by [user]
```

wont.

Comment: Also `[a column name with spaces or reserved chars]`

Comment: Yes. It covers spaces and reserved characters too